# SQL Server performance problem when joining

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have a query, or batch of queries, that I just can't get to play nice :)

```
SELECT 
      C.ID AS cust_id,
      C.State AS cust_state,
      C.PrevState AS cust_previous_state,
      C.ProjectID AS cust_imported_on_project_id,
      C.CampaignID AS cust_imported_on_campaign_id,
      C.Priority AS cust_priority,
      C.Name AS cust_firstname,
      C.Name2 AS cust_lastname,
      C.AllocatedUser AS cust_allocated_user,
      C.ED1 AS cust_social_security_number,
      C.ED2 AS cust_customer_number,
      C.ED3 AS cust_type,
      C.ED4 AS cust_initial_fact_1,
      C.ED5 AS cust_initial_fact_2,
      C.ED6 AS cust_initial_fact_3,
      C.ED7 AS cust_initial_fact_4,
      C.ED8 AS cust_initial_fact_5,
      C.ED9 AS cust_extra_1,
      C.ED10 AS cust_extra_2,
      CED2.ED11 AS cust_extra_3,
      CED2.ED12 AS cust_extra_4,
      CED2.ED13 AS cust_extra_5,
      A.Serial AS address_serial,
      A.PostAddress AS address_postal_address,
      A.PostCode AS address_postal_code,
      A.PostOffice AS address_city,
      A.PhoneNr AS address_phonenumber,
      A.FaxNr AS address_faxnumber,
      A.EMail AS address_email,
      A.Notes AS address_notes,
      A.ED1 AS address_secondary_phonenumber,
      A.ED2 AS address_origin_file,
      A.State AS address_state
FROM TCustomers C WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN TCustED2 CED2 WITH (NOLOCK) ON C.ID = CED2.CustomerID 
    LEFT JOIN TAddresses A WITH (NOLOCK) ON C.AddressNr = A.Serial AND C.ID = A.CustomerID
WHERE C.CampaignID IN(SELECT items FROM dbo.Split('196,195,210,206,205,207,204,200,209,213,197,198,214', ',')) AND C.InsDate > '2011-04-03 00:00:00'
```

This query in itself is very snappy and executes on a million+ rows in a few seconds.
The problem is when I want to use information from the order table to filter my result.

I have tried to join on the Orders table

```
SELECT 
      C.ID AS cust_id,
      C.State AS cust_state,
      C.PrevState AS cust_previous_state,
      C.ProjectID AS cust_imported_on_project_id,
      C.CampaignID AS cust_imported_on_campaign_id,
      C.Priority AS cust_priority,
      C.Name AS cust_firstname,
      C.Name2 AS cust_lastname,
      C.AllocatedUser AS cust_allocated_user,
      C.ED1 AS cust_social_security_number,
      C.ED2 AS cust_customer_number,
      C.ED3 AS cust_type,
      C.ED4 AS cust_initial_fact_1,
      C.ED5 AS cust_initial_fact_2,
      C.ED6 AS cust_initial_fact_3,
      C.ED7 AS cust_initial_fact_4,
      C.ED8 AS cust_initial_fact_5,
      C.ED9 AS cust_extra_1,
      C.ED10 AS cust_extra_2,
      CED2.ED11 AS cust_extra_3,
      CED2.ED12 AS cust_extra_4,
      CED2.ED13 AS cust_extra_5,
      A.Serial AS address_serial,
      A.PostAddress AS address_postal_address,
      A.PostCode AS address_postal_code,
      A.PostOffice AS address_city,
      A.PhoneNr AS address_phonenumber,
      A.FaxNr AS address_faxnumber,
      A.EMail AS address_email,
      A.Notes AS address_notes,
      A.ED1 AS address_secondary_phonenumber,
      A.ED2 AS address_origin_file,
      A.State AS address_state
FROM TCustomers C WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN TCustED2 CED2 WITH (NOLOCK) ON C.ID = CED2.CustomerID 
    LEFT JOIN TAddresses A WITH (NOLOCK) ON C.AddressNr = A.Serial AND C.ID = A.CustomerID
    LEFT JOIN TOrders O WITH (NOLOCK) ON C.ID = O.CustomerID
WHERE C.CampaignID IN(SELECT items FROM dbo.Split('196,195,210,206,205,207,204,200,209,213,197,198,214', ',')) AND 
(C.InsDate > '2011-04-03 00:00:00' OR O.CustomerID NOT NULL OR O.[Date] > '2011-04-03 00:00:00' OR O.Exported IS NULL);
```

This results in an execution time of several minutes.
If I just run the interesting part from `TOrders` it just takes a few seconds to execute.

```
SELECT CustomerID 
FROM TOrders 
WHERE O.CustomerID NOT NULL 
   OR O.[Date] > '2011-04-03 00:00:00' 
   OR O.Exported IS NULL;
```

So the problem is when combining the two. I tried running the TOrders query and pasting the resulting CustomerID's into the main query directly and that was snappy and took around 5-10 seconds. I tried prefetching the interesting data from TOrders and putting it into a temporary table but that didn't make it any faster.

```
CREATE TABLE #ORDERCUSTOMERS (
  CustomerID int
);
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_1 on #ORDERCUSTOMERS (CustomerID);

INSERT #ORDERCUSTOMERS SELECT DISTINCT O.CustomerID FROM LPD1_8.dbo.TOrders O WHERE O.CampaignID IN(SELECT items FROM dbo.Split('196,195,210,206,205,207,204,200,209,213,197,198,214', ',')) AND (O.[Date] > '2011-04-03 00:00:00' OR O.Exported IS NULL);

SELECT 
          C.ID AS cust_id,
          C.State AS cust_state,
          C.PrevState AS cust_previous_state,
          C.ProjectID AS cust_imported_on_project_id,
          C.CampaignID AS cust_imported_on_campaign_id,
          C.Priority AS cust_priority,
          C.Name AS cust_firstname,
          C.Name2 AS cust_lastname,
          C.AllocatedUser AS cust_allocated_user,
          C.ED1 AS cust_social_security_number,
          C.ED2 AS cust_customer_number,
          C.ED3 AS cust_type,
          C.ED4 AS cust_initial_fact_1,
          C.ED5 AS cust_initial_fact_2,
          C.ED6 AS cust_initial_fact_3,
          C.ED7 AS cust_initial_fact_4,
          C.ED8 AS cust_initial_fact_5,
          C.ED9 AS cust_extra_1,
          C.ED10 AS cust_extra_2,
          CED2.ED11 AS cust_extra_3,
          CED2.ED12 AS cust_extra_4,
          CED2.ED13 AS cust_extra_5,
          A.Serial AS address_serial,
          A.PostAddress AS address_postal_address,
          A.PostCode AS address_postal_code,
          A.PostOffice AS address_city,
          A.PhoneNr AS address_phonenumber,
          A.FaxNr AS address_faxnumber,
          A.EMail AS address_email,
          A.Notes AS address_notes,
          A.ED1 AS address_secondary_phonenumber,
          A.ED2 AS address_origin_file,
          A.State AS address_state
      FROM LPD1_8.dbo.TCustomers C WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN LPD1_8.dbo.TCustED2 CED2 WITH (NOLOCK) ON C.ID = CED2.CustomerID 
    LEFT JOIN LPD1_8.dbo.TAddresses A WITH (NOLOCK) ON C.AddressNr = A.Serial AND C.ID = A.CustomerID
    LEFT JOIN #ORDERCUSTOMERS O ON C.ID = O.CustomerID
      WHERE C.CampaignID IN(SELECT items FROM dbo.Split('196,195,210,206,205,207,204,200,209,213,197,198,214', ',')) AND 
    (C.InsDate > '2011-04-03 00:00:00' OR O.CustomerID NOT NULL);

DROP TABLE #ORDERCUSTOMERS;
```

So do you guys have any idea? This will reside in a stored procedure so I want to avoid dynamic SQL if possible. Otherwise that would probably be one way, to fetch the data from TOrders and inject the returned CustomerID's into the IN clause of the main query.
But prehaps there is a similar way to "inject" an array of id's into an IN clause or something?

Comment: Maybe you can try your Query Analysis Tool first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using the order table in your where clause. this means that the query planner can't start removing lines from the customer table early enough. have you tried joining in the order table earlier?

```
SELECT 
      C.ID AS cust_id,
      C.State AS cust_state,
      C.PrevState AS cust_previous_state,
      C.ProjectID AS cust_imported_on_project_id,
      C.CampaignID AS cust_imported_on_campaign_id,
      C.Priority AS cust_priority,
      C.Name AS cust_firstname,
      C.Name2 AS cust_lastname,
      C.AllocatedUser AS cust_allocated_user,
      C.ED1 AS cust_social_security_number,
      C.ED2 AS cust_customer_number,
      C.ED3 AS cust_type,
      C.ED4 AS cust_initial_fact_1,
      C.ED5 AS cust_initial_fact_2,
      C.ED6 AS cust_initial_fact_3,
      C.ED7 AS cust_initial_fact_4,
      C.ED8 AS cust_initial_fact_5,
      C.ED9 AS cust_extra_1,
      C.ED10 AS cust_extra_2,
      CED2.ED11 AS cust_extra_3,
      CED2.ED12 AS cust_extra_4,
      CED2.ED13 AS cust_extra_5,
      A.Serial AS address_serial,
      A.PostAddress AS address_postal_address,
      A.PostCode AS address_postal_code,
      A.PostOffice AS address_city,
      A.PhoneNr AS address_phonenumber,
      A.FaxNr AS address_faxnumber,
      A.EMail AS address_email,
      A.Notes AS address_notes,
      A.ED1 AS address_secondary_phonenumber,
      A.ED2 AS address_origin_file,
      A.State AS address_state
FROM TCustomers C WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN TOrders O WITH (NOLOCK) ON C.ID = O.CustomerID
    LEFT JOIN TCustED2 CED2 WITH (NOLOCK) ON C.ID = CED2.CustomerID 
    LEFT JOIN TAddresses A WITH (NOLOCK) ON C.AddressNr = A.Serial AND C.ID = A.CustomerID
WHERE C.CampaignID IN(SELECT items FROM dbo.Split('196,195,210,206,205,207,204,200,209,213,197,198,214', ',')) AND 
(C.InsDate > '2011-04-03 00:00:00' OR O.CustomerID NOT NULL OR O.[Date] > '2011-04-03 00:00:00' OR O.Exported IS NULL);
```

Comment: This actually got it down quite a bit. now it's ~50sek, which is a lot better than 3-4min, but still far away from the 3 sek per separate query I got. I will try wit a dynamic SQL statement and see if that is faster. Otherwise I will go with this. The statement is used to import data at regular intervals so 50 sek would be ok.

Comment: perhaps indexing the fields TAddresses.Serial and TCustomers.AddressNr would speed things up a bit too.

Comment: TAddresses.Serial is part of TAddresses clustered index, TCustomer.AddressNr is not part of any index though. But would that help since Customers is still the primary table I'm fetching from?

Comment: you're using TCustomers.AddressNr in a join on clause, which ***probably*** forces a full table scan. so indexing that field would with the same probability speed up the query. but at the same time it would likely make inserts on TCustomers somewhat slower :/

Comment: Added the index to check but no noticeable difference. But the current execution time is good enough though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried analyzing your query using the built-in SQL Server Query Optimizer tool?

Comment: Yes I have.. The majority of the tim is spent on the main query (98%). And the majority of the time within that is on a Clustered Index Scan on TCustomers and a Clustered Index scan on TAddresses. It only sais that the #ORDERCUSTOMERS is responsible fo 1% of that query. The interesting part though is that if I remove the TOrders the entire query goes from minutes to four seconds. So I quess it's a bit missleading and the introduction of #ORDERCUSTOMERS, or when using a join, actually makes TCustomers and TAddresses scan throuh it's indexes many, many times. So the TOrders part is the bad guy.

Comment: I am guessing that introducing an `indexed view` is not something that you want to do?

Comment: The system running the DB is a 3:rd party application so I wan't to add as little as possible to it. A single SP is well isolated. I'm not very fimiliar with `indexed views` but I guess you build a view and index it so that the query planner has a better view of how things are connected? I have mostly worked in MySQL before and have some limited knowledge about Sybase and MSSql specific things.

Comment: One drawback is that you have to set certain database `OPTIONS` to make an `indexed view` work. Another is the fact that indexed views impact performance on inserts in the underlying tables. Essentially you create a view `WITH SCHEMABINDING`. Here is the *how to*: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> This will reside in a stored procedure so I want to avoid dynamic SQL if possible.

BAD news. You want dynamic on soemthing like that in that you at least want "with recompile" on the SP, or your first run decides your query plan.

That said, it looks like an expensive oepration. More details depend on the query plan. Maybe you msisan index or two? Please publish the execution plans (assumed & from execution).

Comment: I added indexes on all the columns that was missing it. The individual parts is snappy as hell, but when joining it just dies.

Comment: If using dynamic SQL for this specific part (the SP contains more stuff). Is there a way to transform the one column id containing result into a comma separated string to inject into the `IN` clause without having to create a pointer and traverse the result from a `SELECT id FROM foobar`, which would probably not be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

The ways of the query optimizer are not always predictable. Assuming you have indices on all columns you're joining/filtering on, I'd try the following:

```
OR O.CustomerID NOT NULL
```

appears redundant - as you're using that column in the join condition, it should always evaluate to TRUE. This should mean that the query returns every record, regardless of the dates.

Also, you may find that replacing

```
 WHERE C.CampaignID IN(SELECT items FROM dbo.Split('196,195,210,206,205,207,204,200,209,213,197,198,214', ','))
```

with

```
 WHERE C.CampaignID IN(196,195,210,206,205,207,204,200,209,213,197,198,214)
```

could speed things up. I've found that function evaluation can change the way the query optimizer works in ways that aren't obvious.

Comment: The split is take a string argument of a comma separated string. So this particular string is just for illustration.

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't clear. Edited to reflect what I'm recommending you try.